# Ember unit test computed property with then

Tags: unit-testing, ember.js

I have the following model:
**partner.js**

```
  invoices: hasMany('invoice'),
  resolvedInvoices: computed('invoices', {
    get(){
      let value = null;
      let _this = this;
      this.get('invoices').then(invoices=>{
        _this.set('resolvedInvoices', invoices);
      });
      return value;
    },
    set(key,value) {
      return value;
    }
  }),
```

I try to unit test it:
**partner-test.js**

```
test('test', function(assert) {

  let partner = this.subject();
  let store = this.store();
  // set a relationship
  run(() => {
    let invoice = store.createRecord('invoice', {

    });

    partner.get('invoices').pushObject(invoice);
    console.log(partner.get('resolvedInvoices'));
  });
  assert.ok(true);
});
```

But console.log always shows null. Is it possible to wait till the computed property's then runs, and the new value sets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you say `let value = null;`, but then never set value to anything else, and just return value. So yeah, it would always log null. Probably you want to set `value = this.get('invoices')`, and then return that.